# Filter Table by date vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble filtering a table by date. All the other filters work in the code and the variable(MonthNumber) carries the date into this sub. Moving the ordering of the filters makes no differance.

```
Sub FilterRawDataTbl(HomeCode, MonthNumber, CompanyName)
Sheets("Raw Data").Activate
On Error Resume Next
rawData.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

rawData.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=HomeCode
      
rawData.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
    Criteria1:="=*" & CompanyName & "*", Operator:=xlAnd

rawData.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
    Criteria1:="<=" & MonthNumber, Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

I would like it to filter Before or equal to the date that is carried in the variable.

Comment: `AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<=" & CDbl(DateSerial(Year(Date), MonthNumber + 1, 0)), Operator:=xlAnd`

Comment: Thanks, changed to `rawData.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<=" & CDbl(MonthNumber)` for it to work. Thanks for pointing me in the direction